# Spring Integration - IP - Receiving more than one response

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

I am working on a high-volume integration with using spring integration tcp and I only send a request and receive more than millions of data over one connection and the time between two receiving message is lower than 100 milliseconds.

Here is my context xml and I am using TCPOutboundGateway.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

  <bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.EchoService"
    id="echoService"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.ByteArrayToStringConverter"
    id="javaDeserializer"/>


  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
    apply-sequence="true" deserializer="javaDeserializer"
    host="127.0.0.1"
    id="TCPClientFactory1"
    port="443"
    single-use="false"
    type="client"
  />


  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway
    async="true" close-stream-after-send="false" connection-factory="TCPClientFactory1"
    id="outGateway"
    remote-timeout="10000"
    reply-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
    reply-timeout="10000"
    request-channel="input"
    request-timeout="10"
  />

  <int:channel id="input"/>
  <int:channel id="toSA"/>

  <int:gateway default-request-channel="input"
    id="gw"
    service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.SimpleGateway"/>

  <int:object-to-string-transformer auto-startup="true" id="serverBytes2String"
    input-channel="serverBytes2StringChannel"
    output-channel="toSA"/>

  <int:service-activator
    input-channel="toSA"
    method="test"
    ref="echoService"
  />

  <int:transformer expression="payload.failedMessage.payload + ':' + payload.cause.message"
    id="errorHandler"
    input-channel="errorChannel"/>
</beans>
```

I took an example from github.
My issue is; I can successfully handle and process first received message. But the rest is got below exception.

```
20:21:34.550 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for 127.0.0.1:443:57385:e164052f-64e5-4d41-9d46-4a12bad12cd4
```

I read the source code of TcpOutboundGateway and also read caching client connection factory document but could not found a proper way to achieve solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway is not designed for that scenarion it only supports 1 reply per request.

You can use a pair of outbound/inbound channel adapters, instead of the gateway, for scenarios like this.

The upcoming 5.4 release has an [enhancement to the gateway to support this scenario](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3327).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gary. I might be wrong but when I checked 5.4.4, gateway is still not support this scenario. Right?  I have managed to use channel adaptor with xml configuration but I am trying to convert it to annotation based configuration and I could not find a proper example for annotation based tcp outbound channel. Can you guide me?

Comment: The enhancement was merged into 5.4. On the server side, you can attach both an inbound gateway and outbound channel adapter to the same factory allowing request/reply and arbitrary sends. On the client side, unsolicited messages are sent to the `unsolicitedMessageChannel`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/whats-new.html#x5.4-tcp) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways). That section also has a link to annotation and DSL based configuration.